# Call a constructor with parameters in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have this class:

```
public class Interets {
    static Statement St ;
    public ResultSet rs;

    public Interets(Integer IdUser) throws SQLException, ServletException, IOException{
        String res=" ";


    try{

        ResultSet result = St.executeQuery("SELECT description FROM interets, avoir, consomateur WHERE avoir.id_interet=interets.id_interets AND avoir.id_user=consomateur.code_bar AND consomateur.code_bar="+IdUser+"");

            ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = (ResultSetMetaData) result.getMetaData();


            while(result.next()){         
                String Newligne=System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
            for(int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)

           res=res+Newligne+result.getObject(i).toString();

              System.out.println(res);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erreur dans la requete d'affichage ");
        }

    }
}
```

I want to call its constructor in a JSP like this:

```
<div id="corps"><h1>
<%Interets inte=new Interets(${IdUser})%>
    </h1>
</div>
```

But I'm getting syntax errors like

> "Syntax error on token ")",;expected"

and

> "Syntax error on tokens, misplaced constructs"

so how can I do it.
Thank you

Comment: I already have this method in my servlet:                  public void doInteret (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, ServletException, IOException  {
 
  
  IdUser = (Integer) session.getAttribute("IdUser");
  Interets inte= new Interets();
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `<% ... %>`, you should write **valid** Java code, so you're missing a semicolon `;` in the end of your statement:

```
<%Interets inte=new Interets(${IdUser})%>
                                       ^here you're missing a semicolon...
```

Also, you cannot mix EL with scriptlets, so the code should be:

```
<%
    Integer idUser = (Integer)request.getAttribute("IdUser");
    //if the attribute is stored in HttpSession (probably)
    //or ServletContext (oddly), use the right method to get it
    Interets inte =new Interets(idUser);
%>
```

Just to note, this may solve your current compilation problem but there are several problems in your current design e.g. you're not initializing the `Statement` anywhere in your `Interets` class but still using it in the constructor...

---

You should learn basic Java and basic JDBC first before trying to open a connection to database and print the results in a web environment. I won't dive into any of these topics but rather write a possible solution to your current code, I'll comment the wrong code in order for you to notice what is wrong or what you should not do:

```
public class Interets {
    //static Statement St ;
    //public ResultSet rs;

    public List<String> getDescriptionOfInterets(Integer idUser) {
        String res=" ";
        //these three: Connection, Statement, ResultSet MUST ALWAYS be local
        //variables of a method, NEVER assigned to class field AND NEVER to
        //static variables to avoid synchronization problems in a
        //multithreaded environment such as a web application
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<String> descriptionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            //this is one way to open a database connection
            //you should change it to a database connection pool
            //which is a different topic you should search about
            //since you didn't say which database you're working with
            //I'll assume it's mysql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //similar with the database credentials
            String user = "root";
            String password = "root";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", user, password);
            /*
            ResultSet result = St.executeQuery("SELECT description FROM interets, avoir, consomateur WHERE avoir.id_interet=interets.id_interets AND avoir.id_user=consomateur.code_bar AND consomateur.code_bar="+IdUser+"");

            ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = (ResultSetMetaData) result.getMetaData();
            */
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT description "
                + "FROM interets, avoir, consomateur "
                + "WHERE avoir.id = interets.id AND "
                + "avoir.id?user = consomateur.code_bar AND "
                + "contomateur.code_bar = ?");
            ps.setInt(1, idUser);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            //while(result.next()){
            while (rs.next) {
                //String Newligne=System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
                //for(int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)
                //res=res+Newligne+result.getObject(i).toString();
                //System.out.println(res);
                descriptionList.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle your error! This is very important to check the causes of the problem
            //you should at least print the stacktrace
            //printing a single line saying "oh no! I got an error" doesn't help
            System.out.println("Erreur dans la requete d'affichage.");
            e.printStacktrace();
        } finally {
            //remember to ALWAYS close the opened resources
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
            close(con);
        }
    }

    public void close(ResultSet rs) {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //silent...
            }
        }
    }

    public void close(Statement st) {
        if (st != null) {
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //silent...
            }
        }
    }

    public void close(Connection con) {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //silent...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your JSP:

```
Description of Interets
<table>
<%
    Integer idUser = (Integer)request.getAttribute("IdUser");
    //if the attribute is stored in HttpSession (probably)
    //or ServletContext (oddly), use the right method to get it
    Interets interets = new Interets();
    List<String> descriptionList = interets.getDescriptionOfInterets(idUser);
    for (String description : descriptionList) {
    %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= description %></td>
        </tr>
    <%
    }
%>
</table>
```

Or even better, using [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (assuming your JSP is named "interets.jsp" and in the root package):

```
@WebServlet("/interets")
public class InteretsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Integer idUser = (Integer)session.getAttribute("IdUser");
        Interets interets = new Interets();
        List<String> descriptionList = interets.getDescriptionOfInterets(idUser);
        request.setAttribute("descriptionList", descriptionList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/interets.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And the JSP may look like

```
Description of Interets
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${descriptionList}" value="description">
        <tr>
            <td>${description}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried your solution luigi and the error is gone, thank you, and I corretec thie statement declaration like this :                  static Statement St=null ;     Is that what you meant (I'm sorry I'm new to java). But now the result is not shown in my page istead  the mesage in Exception is shown.

Comment: @user3365621 as noted at the bottom of my answer, there are several problems with your current design. It would be better to review Java basics and JDBC basics first. I'll give a try to add more content to this answer to try to save your current code...

Comment: Luigi when it comes to connection to database I already have a class that does that, so should I rewrite all Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");....etc or can I just instantiate my connection class? (I know my code is a mess but we had only a wekk to learn for the first time jsp servlets and do the project)

Comment: @user3365621 adapt this code as you may need it. This is only a possible solution to your current problem/design. If this class you mention has a field that handles the `Connection`, then it should be redefined as a method that returns the `Connection`, so you can replace `con = DriverManager...` code by `con = yourMethodThatReturnsAConnection`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.I adapted the code you gave, but I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerExceptionerror in line 52 which is :             ps.setInt(1, idUser);                             the query is as follow:                                                             ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT description "+ "FROM interets, avoir, consomateur "+ "WHERE avoir.id_interet = interets.id_interets AND "+ "avoir.id_user = consomateur.code_bar AND "+ "consomateur.code_bar = "+idUser+"");

Comment: @user3365621 seems that your `con` variable has `null` value.